# Image uploaded with Filepond has different size than local file

Tags: filepond

When I upload files with Filepond they stay the exact same size.

However when I upload images with the image preview plugin enabled the uploaded file has a different file size, usually far bigger  that the original file.I assume that the data returned from  createImageBitmap is uploaded and not the file provided to FilePond but that's just a guess.

Does anyone know of a way to upload the original, unmodified file?

I tried disabling the image preview plugin and then the file size doesn't change. But I really like how the image preview looks so this is only a last resort solution. The behaviour is also the same regardless of the server endpoint is used or an .